# Shopify Product Page How To Seperate Links From Metafields

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to show my varian's images in my custom product liquid. I created metafield for variants and added 2 images for each variant.

So I added this code to product liquid;

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id == variant.id %}
        <div class="variant-images" data-variant-id="{{ variant.id }}">
    {{variant.metafields.custom.customproductpageimages }}
        </div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So this is my output;

["variantimagelink.png","variantimagelink2.png"]

I tried for loop to seperate them but this time div turns empty.

How can I seperate them and show them as image?

Because after that I want to use them in slick slider as slider.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image uploaded to a product, you get it from **product.images**. Makes sense right? So if you have the name of an image as per something you stored in a metafield, you'd look through your product images looking for the match. So you can iterate through your product.images and if the name in your metafield matches in the src of the product.image you are examining, there you go. Feed that into an image element and you'll see it on screen.